# How do i add an individual onclick/EventListener function to each row of PHP generated content?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Trying to expand PHP generated divs individually with an onclick event. How do I add an EventListener or onclick function to each div object so that I can expand them individually by clicking on them?

Right now i want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('card').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('card').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

In a for loop:

```
echo "<div class='card z-depth-1'>
      <div class='event-text'>
      <p class='event-time white-text'>" . date('H:i',strtotime($array[$i]['DTSTART'])) . "</p>
      <p class='event-information red-text text-lighten-4'>" . explode("\\,", $array[$i]['SUMMARY'])[0] . " " . $type . " " . str_replace('Lokal : ', '', $array[$i]['LOCATION']) . "</p>
      <p><br><br>Lorem ipsum leo cursus commodo quam dapibus metus dictumst etiam, quisque posuere ut molestie quam ad duis neque quis adipiscing posuere cras vulputate augue curae, leo lacinia diam ullamcorper aenean, ipsum donec luctus quam ad.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>";
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  max-height: 10vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card.expand {
  max-height: 20vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: doesn't `getElementsByClassName` return an array of elements not an individual element?

Comment: Something like that. I'm not that good with Javascript so i clearly need help figuring this out. I've tried with getElementById as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `document.getElementsByClassName('card')` returns a `HTMLCollection` of elements and not a single item, you will have to loop through your cards to attach the event.

Like this:

```
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

for (let card of cards) {
  card.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('expand');
  });
}
```

Comment: Just a point here. `document.getElementsByClassName('card')` won't return an array, but a NodeList object, ok? If you want to use a NodeList object as a real array you'll have to use `Array.from()`.

Comment: About this, @zgood, it is interesting to read https://gomakethings.com/nodelists-vs-arrays/ and https://gomakethings.com/converting-a-nodelist-to-an-array-with-vanilla-javascript/ .

Comment: @EddeAlmeida it returns a `HTMLCollection` not a `NodeList` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)). See working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ncLtz0yo/)

Comment: This worked as expected and with your solution, I did not have the issue that I mentioned in another comment. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, thanks for correcting me, @zgood. Anyway, it is not an array as you said. It is an array-like as the reference you mentioned says.

Comment: I'm trying to add an animation to the expanding, but when clicking to minimize the card there is no animation. I'm using transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out.

Comment: Thank you so much!